# Matlab equation unknown

Tags: image, matlab, find, arguments

I ve got the matlab equation as below:

```
ImageA = GrayscaleImageB(find(GrayscaleImageB >= 0));
```

what does this nested vector `find(GrayscaleImageB >= 0)` does in the brackets of the image `GrayscaleImageB`? is it something like multiply?

Comment: This question is unlikely to help anyone. Just look up the `find` function in [the documents](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). It's nothing like multiply.  There is no specific question about a problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` in that example actually completely unnecessary and does the same thing as

```
ImageA = GrayscaleImageB(GrayscaleImageB >= 0);
```

Which just returns all the pixels of `GrayScaleImageB` that are greater than zero, but as a column vector.

Lets take an example:

```
B = rand(10)  %//Random 10x10 matrix of values between 0 and 1
```

now compare `B >= 0.5` and `find(B >= 0.5)` in your command line. You'll see that the first one returns a 10x10 logical array with the elements set to true where the condition is met and the `find` method returns a column vector of linear indexes of every pixel that met the condition (i.e. was greater than 0.5).

Comment: Lets say , thus, that there is a equation such as this:ImageA = GrayscaleImageB(find(GrayscaleImageC >= 0)); what is the meaning of the nested Array in Array?

Comment: Once again the `find` does nothing. But basically it selects from `ImageB` all the pixels of `ImageC` that are greater than or equal to 0.